# Angular doesn't render the page when I try start up the server

Tags: angular, serve

I've created three components and I've added them to `app.module.ts` (src/app), inside components there're only selectors, simply because those are my purpose.
Angular doesn't render the page when I try start up the server with `ng serve`.

**Versions**

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.3
Node: 8.11.1
OS: linux ia32
Angular: 5.2.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.7.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.11.0

npm: 5.6.0
```

When I try start up

```
ng serve

** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
Date: 2018-04-05T12:05:40.204Z                                                          
Hash: b240b8c528ec8570cab0
Time: 25702ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 3.85 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 25.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 557 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 41.5 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 7.42 MB [initial] [rendered]

webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without further information - please provide your code and/or the console logs.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by It doesn't serve the page? Do you see errors? Is it a blank page?

Comment: Only a blank page

Comment: Could you add the template of the component you are bootstraping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*Angular doesn't render the page when I try start up the server*" / "*Only a blank page*"

If you have **errors in your code**, angular will show a **blank page**, even if it is compiling.

So you need to start checking errors in your browser's developer tools, and checking your code.

Solution: In this case, your problem is in:

`meu-segundo.component.ts`, you close a `h1` label with `h2`, change it to:

`<h1>Welcome To Program</h1>`

You can see this errors by typing **F12** (Developer Tools) in your browser and checking the console.

Comment: See on GitHub: https://github.com/Yuridsm/learning/tree/master/angular/primeiro-projeto/src/app

Comment: @YuriMelo, yes, check the answer

Answer (score 2):

Try it now:

```
ng serve -o
```

option **-o** immediately after the build of the application will launch the default browser with your project

Comment: stayed the same way

Answer (score 1):

Was a temporally problem [check it](https://github.com/angular/tsickle/pull/782)

Answer (score 1):

```
You can try this
```

ng serve --port=4211

after open flowing link http://localhost:4211

Comment: stayed the same way

Comment: Take a look at : https://github.com/Yuridsm/learning/tree/master/angular/primeiro-projeto/src/app

Comment: This only reinitiates the project within your browser since the adress has been changed and there is no existing cache for the designated adress.

Answer (score 1):

If it does run, but the page seems blank. Check the `app.component.ts` file, then in the `@Component` decorator, make sure that `selector` is assigned to the tag that has the same name as the one in your `index.html` tag inside the body, usually the name of that tag would be `app-root`.